# Strange Ionic CLI Error After JS file Change

Tags: node.js, npm, ionic-framework, jetbrains-ide, openfb

I'm using openfb.js in my application,
I had to change 1 line in openfb.js file, while Application was normally working. then something strange happened, 
when I type Ionic serve in the API I get an error, which seems like in someway, Ionic is searching for the Temp file which JetBrains IDE Created while editing, openfb.js__jb__old__1 
What can I do? Any help is very appreciated thanks..
[Question on Ionic forums](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/strange-ionic-cli-error-after-js-file-change/33846)

C:\Users\Imad\myapp>ionic serve

> Live Reload failed to start, error:  EPERM, operation not permitted 'C:\Users\Im
>   ad\myapp\www\js\openfb.js___jb_old___1'
>   server start error: Error: EPERM, operation not permitted 'C:\Users\Imad\myapp\w
>   ww\js\openfb.js___jb_old___1'
>       at Error (native)
>       at Object.fs.statSync (fs.js:797:18)
>       at Gaze._addToWatched (C:\Users\Imad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\
>   node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_
>   modules\gaze\lib\gaze.js:277:14)
>       at Gaze.add (C:\Users\Imad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modul
>   es\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\ga
>   ze\lib\gaze.js:175:8)
>       at new Gaze (C:\Users\Imad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modul
>   es\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\ga
>   ze\lib\gaze.js:74:10)
>       at gaze (C:\Users\Imad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\i
>   onic-app-lib\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\gaze\l
>   ib\gaze.js:86:10)
>       at Object.module.exports [as watch] (C:\Users\Imad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_
>   modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\glob
>   -watcher\index.js:12:17)
>       at Object.runLivereload (C:\Users\Imad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ioni
>   c\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\lib\serve.js:286:9)
>       at Object.start (C:\Users\Imad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_m
>   odules\ionic-app-lib\lib\serve.js:501:38)
>       at C:\Users\Imad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\lib\ionic\serve.js:6
>   9:20
>       at _fulfilled (C:\Users\Imad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_mod
>   ules\q\q.js:787:54)
>       at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\Imad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
>   \ionic\node_modules\q\q.js:816:30)
>       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\Imad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
>   odules\ionic\node_modules\q\q.js:749:13)
>       at C:\Users\Imad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\q\q.js:
>   557:44
>       at flush (C:\Users\Imad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\
>   q\q.js:108:17)
>       at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:503:11)
>       at startup (node.js:129:16)
>       at node.js:814:3
>   There was an error serving your Ionic application: server start error: Error: EP
>   ERM, operation not permitted 'C:\Users\Imad\myapp\www\js\openfb.js___jb_old___1'
>
> ```
> at Error (native)
> at Object.fs.statSync (fs.js:797:18)
> at Gaze._addToWatched (C:\Users\Imad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\
> ```
>
> node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_
>   modules\gaze\lib\gaze.js:277:14)
>       at Gaze.add (C:\Users\Imad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modul
>   es\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\ga
>   ze\lib\gaze.js:175:8)
>       at new Gaze (C:\Users\Imad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modul
>   es\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\ga
>   ze\lib\gaze.js:74:10)
>       at gaze (C:\Users\Imad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\i
>   onic-app-lib\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\gaze\l
>   ib\gaze.js:86:10)
>       at Object.module.exports [as watch] (C:\Users\Imad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_
>   modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\glob
>   -watcher\index.js:12:17)
>       at Object.runLivereload (C:\Users\Imad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ioni
>   c\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\lib\serve.js:286:9)
>       at Object.start (C:\Users\Imad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_m
>   odules\ionic-app-lib\lib\serve.js:501:38)
>       at C:\Users\Imad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\lib\ionic\serve.js:6
>   9:20
>       at _fulfilled (C:\Users\Imad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_mod
>   ules\q\q.js:787:54)
>       at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\Imad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
>   \ionic\node_modules\q\q.js:816:30)
>       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\Imad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
>   odules\ionic\node_modules\q\q.js:749:13)
>       at C:\Users\Imad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\q\q.js:
>   557:44
>       at flush (C:\Users\Imad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\
>   q\q.js:108:17)
>       at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:503:11)
>       at startup (node.js:129:16)
>       at node.js:814:3

Answer (score 0):

The post suggest running this to increase the number of watches that are available.
 run this command line from your terminal ass root and  will be work fine 
`echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p`